# If $\overline{OQ}\times\overline{OP}=r^2 $ then $\angle OAP=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: circles

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q:     if $\overline{OQ}\times\overline{OP}=r^2 $ then  $\angle OAP=\frac{\pi}{2}$

($r$: radius of $C$, $C$: circle, $O$: center  $C$)

[image]

Comment: You would want to use the Pythagorean theorem as well as the assumption in the proposition.

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem is not necessary. Proportionality of sides of similar triangles is enough to derive the relation in virtually a single step.

Comment: Oops I was thinking in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: $AP$ is tangent to circle $C, \angle OAP$ is right angle.  It can be proved by similar triangles $ OAQ, OPA$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that triangle $OQA$ and $OOAP$ are similar by SAS.

Hence $\angle OAP = \angle OQA = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $\Delta AOQ \sim \Delta POA$ by observing that:
$$
\overline{OQ}\times\overline{OP}=r^2 \iff \dfrac{r}{\overline{OP}} = \dfrac{\overline{OQ}}{r}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If the usage of [Law of Sine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) is allowed,

let $\angle OAQ=\beta, \angle OPA=\angle QPA=\alpha$

$\frac{OQ}{ \sin\beta}=\frac r1, \frac{OP}{\sin(\frac\pi2+\beta-\alpha)}=\frac r{\sin\alpha}$

As $OQ\cdot OP=r^2, \sin\alpha=\sin\beta\cdot \sin(\frac\pi2+\beta-\alpha)=\sin\beta\cdot \cos(\beta-\alpha)$

$$\implies 2\sin\alpha=2\sin\beta\cdot \cos(\beta-\alpha)=\sin(2\beta-\alpha)+\sin\alpha$$

$$\implies \sin\alpha=\sin(2\beta-\alpha)$$

$$\implies \alpha=2\beta-\alpha\text{ as } \frac\pi2+\beta-\alpha<\pi\iff \beta-\alpha<\frac\pi2$$

$$\implies \alpha=\beta$$

$$\implies  \angle OAP=\angle OAQ+\angle QAP=\beta+\frac\pi2-\alpha=\frac\pi2$$